# Who rang up Mike to find out where he was after Dan Waxberg flipped?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad, season 5, Mike's nine guys' lawyer Dan Waxberg is caught red handed by the DEA while transferring Mike's cash to his nine men's safe deposits.
Right after that, we learn from a conversation between Steve Gomez and Hank Schrader, overheard by Walt, that the lawyer ratted on Mike. Mike then receives a call asking him where he is, claiming there to be a "small situation with the money" which needs discussing face to face. He replies that he's at the park with his granddaughter in Palomita, leading the DEA right to him.

Who placed this call ? Was it Waxberg ? Or someone from the DEA ?

The caller begins by saying "It's me, can you talk ?" to what Mike replies "I can" so presumably he recognises the speaker's voice and feels safe telling him where he is. I'm inclined to think it's the lawyer, but I can't confidently recognise his voice.

Comment: (Random aside - [do you also speak French](https://housseniawriting.com/question/explication-de-lintrigue-qui-a-appele-mike-pour-savoir-ou-il-se-trouvait-apres-le-retournement-de-dan-waxberg/)?)

Comment: I do ! Where did you get that ?

Comment: I am pretty sure I just googled your question, and that site came up. Weird, I hope that's you otherwise there's some alternate French Movies SE!

Comment: Gee I did not write that ! What just happened here ? I wrote this question myself ! And that is not very good French ;)

Comment: I have no idea! I [opened a question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317703/a-french-clone-of-se) to see if someone has any insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It it is implied that it was the lawyer.

The point of the call was to set Mike up; to lead the DEA to him. This call took place right after we learn that the lawyer flipped. It only makes sense that this call was showing us how the lawyer was working with the DEA to lead them to Mike.

It is not made completely clear why this phone call was necessary. Presumably the lawyer's primary role in helping the DEA was to provide them information about the illegal things Mike had done for Gus. The DEA had been generally tailing Mike anyway, and they new where he lived. It seems like they could have found and arrested him at almost any time without needing the lawyer's help on that specific part.

However, that uncertainty aside, it did seem clear that the phone call was made by the lawyer.

Comment: Could be the DEA et al did not have any actual evidence that would be more than circumstantial, but this phone call ties Mike directly to a crime.